# Two Exchange 2010 servers in different locations - Outlook connection problems

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook

I have two Exchange 2010 servers in two locations (and one Exchange 2007 at one of the places but this one is not really in use nor causing any problems) - one server per site (say site A and site B). Sites are on different network ranges and there is a routed tunnel set up between sites. Users' mailboxes are spread out between those two servers so users access to their mail locally rather than through slow WAN link. There is a DC and DNS server per site, and DNS resolves names correctly.

The problem is with Outlook account configuration - no matter what I do, when the site B Exchange server name is entered in Outlook, Outlook resolves the name to the Exchange server from site A. I tried using the server name (Company-EX02), FQDN (Company-EX02.domain.local) and the IP address but nothing makes any difference (this happens from either site, not just site B).

I might be wrong but as the connection speed seems to be worse now (I did not do proper tests before the change so can't really say for sure) I have a feeling the traffic still goes through slow WAN link but actually multiple times - first the user's mail client speaks to EX01, then EX01 speaks to EX02, then data is moved back to EX01 and finally to user at site B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I read it, you have 2 mailbox databases - one in Site A for the users in Site A and another for Site B for the users in Site B. What's the output of `Get-MailboxDatabase MailboxDBInSiteB | fl RpcClientAccessServer`? Is it the CAS in Site A or Site B?

It should be the CAS in site B, but if it isn't try the cmdlet `Set-MailboxDatabase MailboxDBInSiteB -RpcClientAccessServer CASInSiteB`.

Comment: Spot on! RpcCAS was pointing to Company-EX01 so I ran the second command and it resolves the server name correctly. Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 1):

What roles are installed on the three servers?

In Exchange 2010, internal Outlook clients (i.e. RPC connections) don't connect anymore to mailbox servers, but to Client Access ones; if the CAS role isn't there (or is not configured correctly), it's perfectly possible for clients to connect to the wrong server.

Comment: Site A - There are Mailbox, Client Access, Hub Transport and Management Tools installed at Site B

Comment: Both Sites are configured to Maiblox role, CAS, and Hub Transport as well as Management tools

Answer (score 0):

Exchange is site-aware. Do you have your [network-to-site definitions set up](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730718.aspx) correctly in AD Sites & Services? Also worth checking if you have [assigned the "Global Catalog" role](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733162.aspx) to at least one DC at each site - it will help keep intersite GC query traffic down which is initiated by Outlook and Exchange.

Comment: Sorry about my lousy comments but i can't get used to the fact pressing Enter add a comment rather than goes to another line. There is Global Catalog on DC at each site. And yes, AD Sites and Services are configured and aware of each site / subnet / site link.